# Disable HTML datepicker with calendar icon using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, html-helper

I have the following UI,

I've set when dropdown select "None" Date From and Date To pickers are disabled, **but still calender icon is clickable** this is the issue

[image]

when dropdown select "Other" Date From and Date To pickers are enabled, in correct behaviour

[image]

for this, the code snippet is like this

```
<td>
  <%: Html.DateTimeTextBoxFor(m=>m.DateFrom, "dd/MM/yyyy", new { showpicker = true }) %>
</td>
<td>
  <%: Html.DateTimeTextBoxFor(m=>m.DateTo, "dd/MM/yyyy", new { showpicker = true }) %>
</td>
```

script portion

```
function DropDownChange(isShow)
{
    if(isShow)
    {
     $('#DateFrom').removeAttr('disabled');
     $('#DateTo').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    else
    {
     $('#DateFrom').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
     $('#DateTo').attr('disabled', 'disabled');   
     $('#DateFrom').val('');
     $('#DateTo').val('');  
    }
}
```

I'm trying to hide calender icon or disable the onclick action for this calender button from this

Comment: Please provide text of code instead of images.

Comment: @D-Shih thanks for highlighting added as code

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it will set showpicker's value to false

```
$("#DateFrom").attr('showpicker', false);
```

OR try to  hide the textbox itself

```
$("#DateFrom").hide()
```

Comment: I have tried that, showing error as `TypeError" $(...).prop is not a function`

Comment: Updated ans with .attr, please try.

Comment: then no error, but calender icon still clickable

Comment: Can you try to hide the textbox? with $("#DateFrom").hide()

Comment: then can see textbox disappearing, but still remain the clickable calender icon

Comment: Then i guess there is different html for the datepicker, can you share that code as well?